# Always make dataframe copies in pandas using .copy()?

Tags: python, pandas

I made a copy of a dataframe to test some data transformation in an ipython notebook before applying it by

```
datatest = data
datatest.LAST_RENEWAL_CHANNEL.replace(to_replace="Direct.+", value="Direct", inplace=True, regex=True) # combining direct channels
```

after the test I try to compare the difference

```
print(datatest.LAST_RENEWAL_CHANNEL.value_counts())
print(data.LAST_RENEWAL_CHANNEL.value_counts())
```

But both some the exact same result so apparently the original data was changed!

I later used .copy() to fix the issue. My question is if `datatest = data` is not just making a new dataframe? Therefore when I rerun this cell block in ipython notebook it would have affected my original `data` ?

Comment: How about trying  deepcopy instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way python handles objects.

A variable is a reference to *data* stored in memory, e.g. the statement `x=[1,2,3,4,5]` puts this list into memory and uses `x` to access it. If you assign then `y = x` you create another reference to the list, thus, if you change x, you also change y:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> y=x
>>> x[1] = 99
>>> print(y)
[1, 99, 3, 4, 5]
```

See for example Python's doc on [copy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/copy.html)